# Reading a .byt file into R

Tags: r, dataframe, binary

Gridded daily Near-Surface Wind Speed data from [this source](https://data.gov.au/dataset/ds-dap-csiro%3AWind_Speed/details?q=wind%20speed) has file extensions `.byt` which I am unfamiliar with.

I am attempting to read this data into R for analysis, and so would like to interrogate it by latitude and longitude.

**I have tried to import it into R and explore the data through the terminal but  cannot seem to find a way to get the full dataset into R and subsequently into a useful format.**

So far, I have the following:

```r
to.read = file("~/Near-Surface_Wind_Speed/mcvicar_etal_grl2008/5km/2018/Aust_Wind_5km_20180101_V2.byt", "rb")

readBin(to.read, integer(), n=5, size=2, endian = "little")
```

But this only gives me 5 values and no metadata (i.e. variable names or coordinates)

As I am using a mac,  I then opened the terminal and tried  the  following command:

```
od -t x1 Aust_Wind_5km_20180101_V2.byt
```

which returned a bigger picture of the data, a subset of which is given here:

```
0000000    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0001740    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  0b  0b  0b  0c  0c  0c
0001760    0c  0c  0c  0c  0c  0c  0c  0c  0c  0d  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0002000    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0002060    ff  11  ff  ff  11  10  10  10  10  11  11  11  11  11  11  11
0002100    11  11  11  12  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0002120    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0002660    ff  ff  19  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0002700    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0003020    ff  ff  ff  19  18  18  19  14  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13
0003040    13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  14  14
0003060    14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  15  19
0003100    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0003120    ff  ff  ff  ff  1a  14  15  15  15  15  18  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0003140    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0003460    ff  ff  ff  0c  0a  08  08  08  08  08  08  08  08  08  08  08
0003500    09  0c  0e  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0003520    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0003560    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  11  10  0b
0003600    0b  0b  0b  0b  0c  0c  0c  0d  0d  0d  0d  11  12  ff  ff  ff
0003620    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0004340    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  19  15  ff  ff
0004360    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0004520    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  19
0004540    ff  15  12  12  15  19  19  17  14  10  0d  0d  0d  0e  0e  10
0004560    13  0f  0e  0e  0e  0e  0e  0e  0e  0e  0e  0e  0e  0e  0e  0e
0004600    0e  0e  0e  0e  0f  0f  0f  0f  13  17  18  18  19  ff  ff  ff
0004620    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  1a  18  16
0004640    15  12  14  1a  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0004660    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0005160    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  0c  0b  08
0005200    07  07  07  07  06  08  09  08  09  0b  0e  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0005220    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0005300    11  ff  ff  ff  ff  11  10  0d  09  08  08  0a  0d  11  11  12
0005320    12  12  12  12  12  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0005340    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0006060    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  19  15  ff  19  19  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0006100    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0006240    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  19  19  19  ff  ff  ff
0006260    ff  ff  15  11  11  13  15  13  17  19  14  0e  0e  0e  11  0f
0006300    0e  0e  0e  10  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13
0006320    10  0f  0f  10  10  14  14  17  1a  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0006340    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  1a  17  ff  ff  ff  ff
0006360    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0006700    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  0d  0b  0b  0a  0a  09  09  0b  0d
0006720    0c  0d  0e  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0006740    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0007000    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  11  11  11  11  11  10  0e  0c
0007020    0a  09  09  0b  0d  11  12  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0007040    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0007600    19  12  15  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0007620    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0007760    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  19  19  19  ff
0010000    ff  ff  ff  16  13  13  11  0e  10  11  14  12  0f  0e  0f  0e
0010020    0e  10  13  15  14  14  13  15  18  17  14  11  11  10  0f  0f
0010040    10  15  1a  ff  ff  1a  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0010060    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0010420    ff  0d  0d  0d  0d  0d  0c  0d  ff  0e  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0010440    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0010520    11  11  ff  11  10  0c  0b  0a  09  09  0b  0e  10  11  12  ff
0010540    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0011300    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  19  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0011320    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
*
0011500    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  18
0011520    15  18  1a  ff  1a  17  13  11  14  12  0f  0f  0f  0f  0e  0e
0011540    0f  11  13  16  18  17  16  13  13  0f  10  13  14  14  14  17
0011560    16  ff  ff  ff  ff  1a  1a  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
0011600    ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
```

As this data type is very new to me, this is difficult to produce a reproducible question. Any comments to this  effect are very welcome...
@VincentGuillemot in the comment below directed me to a [meta data file](https://data.csiro.au/dap/ws/v2/collections/38391/data/7693824) which shows  the following information:

```
clc; clear all;

% Lower left  = 112.000, -44.000 [111.975, -44.025]
% Upper right = 154.000, -10.000 [154.025,  -9.975]
% Number of columns = 841
% Number of rows    = 681



rows=681; cols=841;
filename = 'Aust_Wind_5km_20110528_V2.byt';

M = memmapfile(filename,'Format',{'uint8',[cols rows],'x'});
a=M.Data.x;
a = a./15.875;
A=flipud(rot90(a));
imagesc(A);
```

It  seems like  this  may be helpful in determining how many items to read into each row/column in R.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is valuable information on the data format in the file `windspeed_load.m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I struggled to find an answer to this I thought I would post my solution for the aforementioned dataset.

Using the information provided in the metadata file as pointed out by @Vincent Guillemot we can see there are 841 rows and 681 columns with given bounds for lat and long.

So we can read it in using `readBin` where `n=(681*841)`.

```r
to.read = file("~/Dropbox/DataSets/Near-Surface_Wind_Speed/mcvicar_etal_grl2008/5km/2018/Aust_Wind_5km_20180101_V2.byt", "rb")
wind <- readBin(to.read, integer(),n=(681*841),size=1,endian="little")
close(to.read)
```

Then using the `data.table` package  for speed we can give the table a lat and long column and then plot using `ggplot2`

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

windDT <- as.data.table(wind)
windDT$longitude <- rep(seq(112,154,by=0.05),681)
windDT$latitude <- rep(seq(-10,-44,by=-0.05),each=841)
windDT[wind < 0]$wind = NA

ggplot(windDT,aes(longitude,latitude))+
  geom_raster(aes(fill=wind))+
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value="transparent")+
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1)+
  theme_bw()
```